# Code to generate 'fcolorbox' throws error messages - What is the cause?

Tags: errors, color

I'm a new user of TeX. I'm actually writing my first document. I started to type a basic equation and I want to colorize it in a box.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{COMMENT RÉSOUDRE UNE ÉQUATION ?}}
\end{center}

\fcolorbox{brun}{chamois}{\parbox{\linewidth}
{\begin{center}
Résoudre l'équation (E): 
$(x^{2} + 1)^{2} = (x^ {2} - 1)^{2} 
$\ d'inconnue x $\in \mathbb{R} }
$\end{center}
\end{document}}
```

When I press <kbd>F1</kbd>, I got many errors regarding line 20? What's wrong?

Regards

Comment: Why is there a second `}` after `\end{document}` should that `}` be after `\end{center}`?

Comment: your last math expression `$\in \mathbb{R} }$` has one `{` and two `}` but you should be using display math not `center` for equations.

Comment: I did what you all said.
Now, I only have one error message:
! File ended while scanning use of \color@b@x.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> maths1.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Emergency stop.
<*> maths1.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
[...]
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: You should read up about logical markup. Don't use manual centring and font size settings; rather, use the appropriate environment for what you're trying to do: `equation` for displayed equations, `\maketitle` to get the document title and so on.

Comment: Please use a more specific title for your question!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if there's a package which uses French colour names out of the box, so I've substituted red and yellow. Please note that `color` is very limited in the number of predefined colours it has, although you can define new ones as you like, and you can give them French names, or any name you want really.

But for the purposes of fixing this error, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\large \textbf{COMMENT RÉSOUDRE UNE ÉQUATION ?}}
\end{center}

\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\parbox{\linewidth}{
    \begin{center}
      Résoudre l'équation (E):
      $(x^{2} + 1)^{2} = (x^{2} - 1)^{2}$
      d'inconnue $x \in \mathbb{R}$
    \end{center}
  }
}

\end{document}
```

I've moved your `x` inside `$ ... $` for `$x \in \mathbb{R}$` and tidied up some of your code formatting to make it easier to see where you went wrong.

Your main mistake was you needed `\parbox{\linewidth}{foo}` with braces around `foo`. You had mistakenly put your closing brace after `\mathbb{R}`, within `$ ... $` and within the `center` environment.

You also had a `}` after `\end{document}`.

This should work, although I'll leave you to select the colours you want to use, as I have no idea what chamois is supposed to look like!

[image]

Also, consider using display math: `\[ ... \]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\large \textbf{COMMENT RÉSOUDRE UNE ÉQUATION ?}}
\end{center}

\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{
    \[
      \text{Résoudre l'équation (E): }
      (x^{2} + 1)^{2} = (x^{2} - 1)^{2}
      \text{ d'inconnue } x \in \mathbb{R}
    \]
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: « chamois » is ‘buff’ – it's the name of a kind of wild goat which lives in the Alps.

Comment: @Bernard I see, thanks :) Nice answer, btw, I think I actually prefer yours :)

Comment: I think they're complementary. You give more useful details for a beginner.

Answer (score 7):

You have two closing `}` wrongly placed. I suppose you want one  of these: (as I don't know how the  ‘brun’ and ‘chamois’ colours are defined, I replaced them with (hopefully) similar colours from the `svgnames` palette. Also, your `\parbox` can't have a width of `\linewidth`, otherwise it will overflow the rightmargin:

```
\documentclass[french, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{brun}{Brown}  
\colorlet{chamois}{Tan}  
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large \textbf{COMMENT RÉSOUDRE UNE ÉQUATION ?}
\end{center}

\noindent\fcolorbox{brun}{chamois}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
{\centering Résoudre l'équation (E):
$(x^{2} + 1)^{2} = (x^ {2} - 1)^{2}
$\ d'inconnue $ x \in \mathbb{R} $
}}
\bigskip

\noindent\fcolorbox{brun}{chamois}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
{\begin{center}%
 Résoudre l'équation (E):
$(x^{2} + 1)^{2} = (x^ {2} - 1)^{2}
$\ d'inconnue $ x \in \mathbb{R} $
\end{center}%
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use your own colors, you can define them as shown in the code below, using `\definecolor` like this:

`\definecolor{name}{color model}{values}`

*name* = any name your color is called by.
*color model* = RGB, HTML, rgb, cmyk, gray
*values* = depends on model and can be either hex, integer or float values, see code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%extended color tables
\usepackage{xcolor}

%define custom colors here. I took some values which are close estimates.
\definecolor{chamois1}{RGB}{239,224,185}
\definecolor{chamois2}{rgb}{0.94,0.88,0.73} %percentage based
\definecolor{brun1}{cmyk}{0, 34, 90, 22}
\definecolor{brun2}{HTML}{#DEB887}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{COMMENT RÉSOUDRE UNE ÉQUATION ?}}
\end{center}

\fcolorbox{brun}{chamois}
{\parbox{\linewidth}
    {
        some equation in here! use style as explained by others.
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Result: [image]